# RecyclerView's items are showing First Time in Tablayout but not in Second Time

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have some problem regarding `TabLayout` with `ViewPager`. I have implemented `RecyclerView` in Fragments of `Tablayout`. This `TabLayout` is implemented on a `Fragment` of Nevigation Drawer's item.

When I click the view of Nevigation Drawer'Fragments with `TabLayout` open and RecyclerView's items are also showing on first time . But Clicking on the second time of `NevigationDrawer`, RecyclerView's items aren't  showing. Why...?

```
public class DashBoardRequest extends Fragment implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board_request, container, false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new AcceptedClientClass(), "Accepted");
        adapter.addFragment(new RejectedClientClass(), "Rejected");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** for this or use **viewpager. setOffscreenPageLimit()**

Comment: It solved the Problem using FragmentStatePagerAdapter() .Thanks Rahul Khurana g. Your valuable idea solved my problem .Thanks very Much.

Comment: Can i post this as answer?

Comment: yes you can post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this:-

Solved:-Replacing with FragmentStatePagerAdapter   from  FragmentPagerAdapter

public class DashBoardRequest extends Fragment implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

```
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dash_board_request, container, false);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) { }

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager){
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new AcceptedClientClass(), "Accepted");
    adapter.addFragment(new RejectedClientClass(), "Rejected");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** for this or use **viewpager. setOffscreenPageLimit()** according to your requirement.